# azkaban solo - log retention period as 12 weeks?

Tags: azkaban

azkaban-solo-2.5.0 execution log seems to deleted after 1 day. 
But Its document says azkaban has log retention period as 12 weeks.

Which part am I confusing?

How can I save execution log more longger?

Answer (score 1):

execution log of azkaban solo is saved to two places.

One is saved to H2 database, and retention of that h2 database 'execution_logs' table is controlled by property 'azkaban.execution.logs.retention.ms' in 'conf/azkaban.properties'. [azkaban.execution.logs.retention.ms is introduced in this commit](https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban/commit/b2cea6b)

On is saved to filesystem, and retention of that file directory logs is controlled by property 'execution.dir.retention'. (See FlowRunnerManager in azkaban)

So setting property 'execution.dir.retention' to 7776000000 (== 3 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) should leave executionDir during 3 month.